# INSERT SELECT SQL Query with Variables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to INSERT record(s) where some of the fields in the record(s) come from one table and the rest of the fields are created from variables. Here is the INSERT SELECT query where I am trying to create the record(s):

```
    DECLARE @projid INT
    ,@status INT
    ,@created DATETIME
    ,@duedate DATETIME
    ,@numdays INT
    ,@divid INT

    SET     @divid = 
        (SELECT DIVID
        FROM DIV
        WHERE StepOrder=1)
    SET     @numdays =
        (SELECT CompTarget
        FROM DIV
        WHERE DIVID=@divid)
    SET     @projid = 10
    SET     @status = 0
    SET     @duedate = 
        DATEADD(day,@numdays,@created)
    SET     @created = '4/18/2017'

    INSERT INTO DIVTasks (ProjectID, GroupID, Status, Created, DueDate, DIVID)

    SELECT @projid, GroupID, @status, @created, @duedate, DIVID
    FROM DIV
    WHERE StepOrder=1
```

There are 3 records with the StepOrder the equals 1 and they have different "CompTarget" numbers.

What I need it to do is take the "Created" date add the "CompTarget" number and return the "DueDate" for each record.

The above query returns this error but does enter 3 records with the "DueDate" as Null:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I think problem is in `SET     @divid =...` or  `SET     @numdays =`. One of two sub queries return more than 1 result. Try to check it...

Comment: `SELECT DIVID FROM DIV WHERE StepOrder=1` is returning more than one record. The condition `StepOrder=1` does not guarantee uniqueness in that table and this generates the error in combination with the `SET`

Comment: Also what is the point of all your `set` calls if you are just going to use them in a `SELECT` statement for your insert? Seems like a lot of redundant/unnecessary code.

Comment: Yes you are correct: Line 8 is the "SET @divid = ..." this does return more than 1 result...problem is I don't know how to fix it?

Comment: `this does return more than 1 result` <= What are you expecting there? Will all records return the same value and you just need the first one? Are they different and you want an insert for each record? Only you can figure that part out, everyone else would just be guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both

```
SET     @divid = 
    (SELECT DIVID
    FROM DIV
    WHERE StepOrder=1)
```

and

```
SET     @numdays =
    (SELECT CompTarget
    FROM DIV
    WHERE DIVID=@divid)
```

will cause the same error, since you wrote there are 3 records with StepOrder equals 1 in that table.

However, I think you are over complicating things.
Try this `insert....select` instead:

```
DECLARE @projid INT = 10
       ,@status INT = 0
       ,@created DATETIME = '2017-04-18' -- note the change of format here!
INSERT INTO DIVTasks (ProjectID, GroupID, Status, Created, DueDate, DIVID)

SELECT @projid, GroupID, @status, @created, DATEADD(day,CompTarget,@created), DIVID
FROM DIV
WHERE StepOrder=1
```

Note - using `yyyy-mm-dd` as the date's  string representation format makes it unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks Zohar Peled...yes sometimes I do over think the issue. Also thanks for the date format tip.  I will use it!

Comment: Glad to help :-)